# Laravel 5 : How to get the value in data attribute using vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I am new in vue js. In our app, we have validation if this value is already exists in the database. I want to improve it by making it a dynamic. So I added to put data attribute in my field whenever the user type anything. My value in mthe data attribute is the table where I will check if this value already exist.

**Add.vue**

```
<label>Code <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" name="code" @keyup="checkCOACode" v-model="coa_code" class="form-control" :data-table="chart_of_accounts">
```

**Add.vue in my method**

```
checkCOACode(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var code = this.coa_code;
    var x    = event.target.getAttribute('data-table');

    alert(x);
    return false;
    axios.post("/checkIfCodeExists", {code:code})
        .then((response)  =>  {
            var code_checker = '';
            if (response.data == 0) {
                $('.add-chart-of-account').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');

            }else{
                $('.add-chart-of-account').attr('disabled','disabled');
                code_checker    =   'Code is already exist';
            }
            this.coa_checker_result = code_checker;
        });
},
```

My value in my x is null.

Question: How do I get the value of my data attribute?

Comment: What is `event` in `event.target.getAttribute('data-table');`? Shoudn't it be `e.target` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value of `data` attribute in `vue` by adding `ref` attribute to your text element

```
<input type="text" ref="coaCode" name="code" @keyup="checkCOACode" v-model="coa_code" class="form-control" :data-table="chart_of_accounts">
```

And then get that attribute like

```
checkCOACode(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const coa = this.$refs.coaCode
    const coaCode = coa.dataset.table
    alert(coaCode);
    return false;

},
```

Comment: Gives me an undefined

Comment: chart_of_accounts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Comment: then you have to add  `chart_of_accounts` in your `data(){ return  { chart_of_accounts: 'your value' } }`method

Comment: IS `chart_of_accounts` is your dynamic value or it is a fix string ?

Comment: It is a fix string. that is my name of the table.

Comment: then remove `:` from `:data-table="chart_of_accounts"`